# Is it possible typeset a \numexpr-calculated number stored in a macro without having to use \the?

Tags: macros, conditionals

For the MWE below, using `\the` with `\NextShiftIndex` makes the document run correctly, however, I would like to know if it is possible to make the calculated number stored in `\NextShiftIndex` not need `\the` to be typeset as done with that stored in `\CurrentShift`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

    \edef\CurrentShift{2}
    \edef\NextShift{\numexpr\CurrentShift + 1\relax}
    
    \ifnum \CurrentShift = 2
        \def\CurrentShiftIndex{2\textsuperscript{nd}}
        \def\NextShiftIndex{\NextShift\textsuperscript{rd}}
    \else
            \ifnum \CurrentShift = 3
                \def\CurrentShiftIndex{3\textsuperscript{rd}}
                \def\NextShiftIndex{\NextShift\textsuperscript{th}}
            \else
                \def\CurrentShiftIndex{\CurrentShift\textsuperscript{th}}
                \def\NextShiftIndex{\NextShift\textsuperscript{th}}
        \fi
    \fi
    
    \CurrentShiftIndex\\
    \NextShiftIndex

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\number` instead of `\the` if you don't like `\the` also of course you can put that into the macro so you don't have to use it when you use the command.

Comment: `\NextShift` is defined to be `\numexpr 2+ 1\relax` so will always have value 3, is that what you intended??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is `next = current +1`. I think I didn't fix it.

Comment: no it is defined as I said, put `\show\NextShift` to see its definition. you used  edef so the `\CurentShift` is expanded at definition time and replaced by 2

Comment: it is rather hard to guess the intention of the code as it is all at the top level, you set currentshift to 2 then test if it is 2 or 3  or something else, so only the first branch can ever execute

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I am testing the logic of reading currentshift from another file. So, I need to read currentshift then calculate the nextshift.

Comment: that would be `\edef\NextShift{\the\numexpr\CurrentShift + 1\relax}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your last suggestion gets me this error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 22.`. Replacing `\edef` with `\def` makes your suggestion work.

Comment: perhaps you get that error in your original document but you would not get that error in the code here

Comment: not related but maybe `\ifcase` is more convenient here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like these? :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ---- Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{plain}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth-3cm
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+2cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1cm\relax
\marginparsep=2mm
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr2cm-2\marginparsep\relax
\textheight=\paperheight
\advance\textheight-3cm
\topmargin=\dimexpr-1in+1cm\relax
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \global\footskip=\dimexpr 1cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                               +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
}%
\parindent=0pt
\flushbottom
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*\OrdinalNumber[1]{%
  \the\numexpr(#1)\relax
  \textsuperscript{\ifcase\the\numexpr(#1)\relax th\or st\or nd\or rd \else th\fi}%
}%
\newcommand*\advanceMacro[2][1]{%
  \edef#2{\the\numexpr(#2)+(#1)\relax}%
}%
% \advanceMacro can be prefixed with \global.

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

Initialize \verb|\CurrentShift|:\smallskip

\verb|\def\CurrentShift{0}|\def\CurrentShift{0}\\%
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}|\advanceMacro{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro[2+3]{\CurrentShift}|\advanceMacro[2+3]{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift-4}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift-4}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift*2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift*2}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceMacro[\numexpr5-10\relax]{\CurrentShift}|%
\advanceMacro[\numexpr5-10\relax]{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift-4}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift-4}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift*2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift*2}

\newpage

Initialize \verb|\CurrentShift|:\smallskip

\verb|\def\CurrentShift{3}|\def\CurrentShift{3}\\%
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Initialize \verb|NextShift|:\smallskip

\verb|\def\NextShift{27}|\def\NextShift{27}\\%
\verb|\NextShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\NextShift}.\smallskip

Define \verb|\NextShift| to yield the result of (\verb|\CurrentShift|+1):\smallskip

\verb|\advanceMacro[-\NextShift+\CurrentShift+1]{\NextShift}|%
\advanceMacro[-\NextShift+\CurrentShift+1]{\NextShift}\\
\verb|\NextShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\NextShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Initialize \verb|\CurrentShift|:\smallskip

\verb|\def\CurrentShift{3}|\def\CurrentShift{3}\\%
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Initialize \verb|NextShift|:\smallskip

\verb|\def\NextShift{\CurrentShift}|\def\NextShift{\CurrentShift}\\%
\verb|\NextShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\NextShift}.\smallskip

Define \verb|\NextShift| to yield the result of (\verb|\CurrentShift|+1):\smallskip

\verb|\advanceMacro{\NextShift}|\advanceMacro{\NextShift}\\
\verb|\NextShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\NextShift}.\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+1}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+1}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+2}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+2}\\
\verb|\OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+3}| yields: \OrdinalNumber{\NextShift+3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\CurrentShift{0}%
\newcommand*\ShiftIndex[1]{%
  \the\numexpr(#1)\relax
  \textsuperscript{\ifcase\the\numexpr(#1)\relax th\or st\or nd\or rd \else th\fi}%
}%
\newcommand*\advanceCurrentShift[1][1]{%
  \edef\CurrentShift{\the\numexpr(\CurrentShift)+(#1)\relax}%
}%
% \advanceCurrentShift can be prefixed with \global.

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\hrule height 0pt\kern-1in

\verb|\def\CurrentShift{0}|\def\CurrentShift{0}\\%
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift|\advanceCurrentShift\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift|\advanceCurrentShift\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift|\advanceCurrentShift\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift|\advanceCurrentShift\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift[5]|\advanceCurrentShift[5]\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift-4}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift-4}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift*2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift*2}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb|\advanceCurrentShift[\numexpr5-10\relax]|\advanceCurrentShift[\numexpr5-10\relax]\\
\verb|\CurrentShift| is defined as \texttt{\meaning\CurrentShift}.\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift-4}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift-4}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+1}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+2}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift+3}\\
\verb|\ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift*2}| yields: \ShiftIndex{\CurrentShift*2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before scrolling down through your answer, I was sure it is you because of the unique answer output :) You should call this layout output your "signature answer". Thanks for the help and I will return to you in case I don't get something.

Comment: @Diaa I do not know exactly what you mean. :-)  In my TeX examples I play with the parameters for the margins when the beauty of the type area is not important, and when I wish the output of the example to fit on exactly one page, and I can't do it any other way. Often I wish this out of laziness, because then I can select the page of the pdf file in the pdf viewer, copy it to the clipboard and from there paste it directly as an image into my StackExchange response. :-)